# android - В приложение произошла ошибка

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

Я разрабатываю приложение, которое использует AppCompatActivity. На api 21+ все нормално работаеть а не запускается приложение на api 19 или меньше с сообщением проложение остановлено. Хочу чтобы на api меньше 19 исползовалься материальный дизайн.

Файл **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="tj.rs.materialdesignexample.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Файл **gradle.build**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tj.rs.materialdesignexample"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Файл **MainActivity.java**

```
package tj.rs.materialdesignexample;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Приложение остановлено" это, конечно, информативно, но хотелось бы увидеть логи.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить библиотеки дизайна и поддержки `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'` под ваш `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во время построения инструментарий Android берет ваши ресурсы, код и файл
AndroidManifest.xml (содержащий метаданные приложения) и преобразует их
в файл .apk . Полученный файл подписывается отладочным ключом, что позволяет
запускать его в эмуляторе. (Чтобы распространять файл .apk среди пользователей,
необходимо подписать его ключом публикации. Дополнительную информацию
об этом процессе можно найти в документации разработчика Android по адресу
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html.)

Необходимо подписать apk с ключом публикации.